# Why is hasNextInt() returning false here?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

This is my first time scanning from a file in Java. I'm trying to read a list of integers from one text file, operate on them, and then read them to another file. The initial file looks like this:

```
1234
9876
2345
```

I'm using a while loop and reading with hasNextInt (after running the program and checking the initial text file, I'm sure the values are there), but I'm getting zero output to the new text file, so I assume hasNextInt() is returning false. To be sure, I simply skipped the scan and operated directly on each ArrayList element using a for loop, and the output was written to the new file perfectly. Here's my code:

```
    try {
        File inFile = new File("input.txt");
        File outFile = new File("output.txt");

        FileWriter inWriter = new FileWriter(inFile);
        FileWriter outWriter = new FileWriter(outFile);
        Scanner inReader = new Scanner(inFile);

        numberArray.add(1234); //Adding numbers to an array that was previously initialized
        numberArray.add(9876);
        numberArray.add(2345);

        System.out.println("The raw numbers are:");

        for (int n : numberArray) {
            inWriter.write(n + "\r\n");
            System.out.println(n);
        }

        System.out.println("\nThe new numbers are:");

        while (inReader.hasNextInt()) {
            int newNumber = inReader.nextInt();
            int checkDigit = (newNumber / 7);
            int finalNumber = (newNumber % checkDigit);
            outWriter.write("" + newNumber + finalNumber + "\r\n");
            System.out.println("" + newNumber + finalNumber);
        }

        inWriter.close();
        outWriter.close();
        inReader.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        System.out.println("There was a problem with the inFile file");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("There was a problem opening the outFile file");
    }
```

Comment: What kind of debugging have you done? Have you attempted to show the input at the time (e.g. readLine)? From the tutorials I read you should be using hasNext(), followed by hasNextInt(). - http://javatutorialhq.com/java/util/scanner-class-tutorial/hasnextint-method-example/

Comment: I am not sure about this, so I am not posting this as answer, but you are reading and writing to the same file at the same time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to close the inWriter prior to reading in the numbers from the file.

inWriter won't output the text to the file until it is closed, so your reader isn't seeing anything because technically nothing is there yet.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that. Exactly what I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are parsing with the scanner the file. As you are getting the numbers of the file the scanner advances, and when you have read all the numbers the scanner reaches the ends and stay right there.... at *the end of the file* yelling that there are more things to scan.

So at the end you should use the numbers store in the array in order to avoid re-scan the entire file again.

Does this work for you?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      ArrayList<Integer> numberArray = new ArrayList<>();
      File inFile = new File("input.txt");
      File outFile = new File("output.txt");

      FileWriter inWriter = new FileWriter(inFile);
      FileWriter outWriter = new FileWriter(outFile);
      Scanner inReader = new Scanner(inFile);

      numberArray.add(1234); // Adding numbers to an array that was previously initialized
      numberArray.add(9876);
      numberArray.add(2345);

      System.out.println("The raw numbers are:");

      for (int n : numberArray) {
        inWriter.write(n + "\r\n");
        System.out.println(n);
      }

      System.out.println("\nThe new account numbers are:");

      for (int newNumber : numberArray) { // re-use the array.. no need to scan the file again.
        int checkDigit = (newNumber / 7);
        int finalNumber = (newNumber % checkDigit);
        outWriter.write("" + newNumber + finalNumber + "\r\n");
        System.out.println("" + newNumber + finalNumber);
      }

      inWriter.close();
      outWriter.close();
      inReader.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
      System.out.println("There was a problem with the inFile file");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      System.out.println("There was a problem opening the outFile file");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely correct. This is what I meant when I said I tested with an array and it DOES work. I understand that there really isn't much purpose in scanning the file again (in fact, I'd prefer this method), but I was also interested in knowing why scanning with hasNextInt wasn't working as well.

Comment: @jt90133 glad of help someone. Continue struggling... is the only way of learning.

Comment: For the `"\r\n"` "end of line", you should use instead  `System.lineSeparator()`

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to make a note of that, now.

Answer (score 0):

You are not flushing/closing the inwriter stream before using it again in the inReader stream.